# Get Lat and Long from a string

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a variable string lng and a varibale string lat.

I want to get the lat and the lng stocked in this 2 variable.

My code:

```
String latitude = jresponse.getString("lat");

String longitude jresponse.getString("lng");

LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); **doesn't work** 

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Last Position"));
```

THANKS

Comment: Just cast it to numbers

Comment: If you can get Location instead of LatLng ?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
String latitude = jresponse.getString("lat");
String longitude jresponse.getString("lng");
LatLng location = new LatLng(Long.parseLong(latitude),Long.parseLong(longitude)); 
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Last Position"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Long latitude = Long.parseLong(jresponse.getString("lat"));
Long longitude  Long.parseLong(jresponse.getString("lng"));
LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude,longitude); 
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Last Position"));
```